# android VideoView Orientation Change not working and video loading is too slow

Tags: android, video, video-streaming

Hi every one i am making a app for playing video and i am using following layout
for portait

```
 <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayoutRoot"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="7dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/video_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />

    </FrameLayout>
```

for landscape

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayoutRoot"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="7dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/video_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
            />
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />
    </FrameLayout>
```

But it is not playing video full screen mode when i change orientation its taking half of screen when i changing orientation to landscape

Comment: I have problem working with orientation .and have also tried relative layout

Answer (score 0):

It will be helpful for you.

```
 @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

And single layout will work for both portrait and landscape. There is no need to make separate layout for landscape